# Spliting the text with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a **sample** from a text: The whole text is here: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/P0N8BVPR)

```
Dr. Trischler  (FDP): Meine Damen und Herren! 
Ich möchte von vornherein als einer der Flücht-
lingsvertreter in diesem Hause meiner Freude 
darüber Ausdruck verleihen, daß die Anträge zur 
Linderung der Not der Flüchtlinge  aus allen Par-
teien kommen, daß sich hier Regierung und Oppo-
sition anscheinend einig in der Auffassung sind, 
daß dieses Problem ein allgemeines ist, daß wir 
alle gemeinsam zusammenarbeiten müssen. Weil 
ich weiß, daß hier das nötige Verständnis vor-
handen ist, will ich mich auch aller Ausführungen 
enthalten, die irgendwie allgemeiner Natur sind. 
Ich will nicht über die Notwendigkeit der Linde-
rung der Not usw. sprechen, sondern ich will zu 
einzelnen Fragen, die in diesen verschiedenen An-
trägen angeschnitten sind, kurz Stellung nehmen. 

Die Frage des  gerechten Ausgleichs.  Auch meine 
Fraktion ist hier selbstverständlich für einen ge-
rechten, gleichmäßigen Ausgleich über alle Länder 
hinweg. Auch wir lehnen wie die Mehrheit in 
diesem Hause es ab, daß man unter den Flücht-
lingen irgendwelche Gruppierungen macht und 
daß für die einzelnen Gegenden die oder jene be-
vorzugt behandelt  werden sollen 

Zur Frage der  Freiwilligkeit:  Ich habe das Ge-
fühl, daß mein Vorredner von zweierlei Frei-
willigkeit gesprochen hat. Einmal sehe ich die 
Frage der Freiwilligkeit vom Standpunkt der Hei-
matvertriebenen aus. In dieser Frage sind wir der 
Meinung, daß keinerlei Zwang angewendet werden 
darf. Wir kennen aus der Vergangenheit auch ver-
schiedenen „freiwilligen" Zwang; auch dies würden 
wir ablehnen. Wir können es den Menschen nicht 
zumuten, daß sie noch einmal gezwungen werden, 
von dort wieder wegzugehen, wo sie bereits 
o einigermaßen eine neue Heimstätte gefunden ha-
ben. — Die zweite Freiwilligkeit ist die Frage der 
Freiwilligkeit der Länder, wieweit sie diesen Aus-
gleich für sich wollen oder nicht. Hier können wir 
nun vorerst ruhig abwarten, wie weit die eigene 
Bereitwilligkeit gehen wird und wieweit es not-
wendig sein müßte, den Artikel  119  des Grund-
gesetzes in Anwendung zu bringen. Jedenfalls 
nehmen wir zu diesem Ausgleich den Standpunkt 
ein, daß es notwendig ist, daß der Ausgleich 
erfolgt und ausreichend durchgeführt wird. 
Das, was wir jetzt hören, es sei geplant, bis Ende 
1950 300 000 umzusiedeln, ist bestimmt keine Lö-
sung. Denn wir haben von den Vorrednern zu die-
sem Thema bereits gehört, daß soundso viele Flücht-
linge wieder neu zuströmen, so daß es Ende 1950 
wahrscheinlich so aussehen wird, daß sich praktisch 
gar nichts geändert hat, weil dieselben Länder, die 
Flüchtlinge abgeben, sehr bald wieder mindestens 
ebenso viele aufgenommen haben werden. 

Präsident Dr. Köhler:  Bevor wir fortfahren, darf 
ich zunächst diesen Antrag zur Geschäftsordnung 
zur Aussprache stellen. Wird das Wort zur Un-
terstützung des Antrags auf vorläufige Aussetzung 
der ersten Beratung der Drucksache Nr. 17 ge-
wünscht? — Bitte, Herr Abgeordneter Kiesinger.
```

I want to split the text in to sections for every Speaker. Thats mean, if I found a Speaker, the section until the next speaker is the text from the previous Speaker.

A Speaker is e.g.: `Dr. Trischler  (FDP):` or the `Präsident Dr. Köhler:`

And I want to split the text, before the matched Speaker. So I can separate the text to each speaker.

My Code:

```
def regex_tokenizer(text):

    regex = r"(\s+(?=(Vizepräsident|Präsident)([\s])([A-Z])([A-z])........:))|(\s+(?=([A-Z]+[a-z]*)([\s]*)(\([A-Z]*\))))"

    splitedtext = re.split(regex, text)

    return splitedtext

def search(splitedtext):

    searched = [s for s in splitedtext if "Bonn" in s]

    print(search())
```

For a search in the splitted list I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Usersx/check_pdfs.py", line 59, in <module>
    search(splitedtext=regex_tokenizer(text=read_file()))
  File "/Usersx/check_pdfs.py", line 46, in search
    searched = [s for s in splitedtext if "Bonn" in s]
  File "x/check_pdfs.py", line 46, in <listcomp>
    searched = [s for s in splitedtext if "Bonn" in s]
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I cannot find the problem. Is the problem on my regex? or on the regex method? or on the search list comprehension?

Comment: Can't comment on the accuracy of that regex, but the reason you're seeing that error is because there are `None` values in your list. Try `filter(None, splitedtext)` before searching.

Comment: In case it helps anyone anwsering, here's the regex without all the extra capturing groups and with the terrible `[A-z]` corrected into `[A-Za-z]` : `\s+(?=(?:Vizepräsident|Präsident)\s[A-Z][A-Za-z].{8}:)|\s+(?=[A-Z]+[a-z]*\s*\([A-Z]*\))`

Comment: I saw the full text from pastebin, and from my PoV it is too complicate to achieve with regex. i would advise you to manually write all speakers in a list and then using string functions to split what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have an over complicated regex. Try this instead:

```
regex = r"(^.*:)"
```

this will result in the following:

```
['', 'Dr. Trischler  (FDP):', ' Meine Damen und Herren! ...', ...]
```

Comment: because the text is more complicated then the sample. There are to much cases with : before a word.

Comment: Fair enough, but note that this only matches if the pattern is at the beginning of a line, and not any `word:` combination.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this Regex works for you:

```
((?:Dr\.|Vizepräsident|Präsident).*(?<!cid)):((?:(?!Dr\.|Vizepräsident|Präsident).*\n)*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/viq5u6/1)